# How to restrict Django user account creation to given usernames / addresses / practical values?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-allauth

We've set up Django user account creation / login through [this tutorial](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-login-and-logout-tutorial), and we've restricted content to auth'd users only through the likes of `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` and `if request.user.is_authenticated`. All works great. But there's still nothing stopping anyone from going to the site and registering an account providing any values for username / email address / password.

We want to restrict user account creation to specific usernames / emails / IPs / any practical value. Could we check if a value is in some whitelist by inserting something like `if email in ['whitelistedemail@example.com']:` somewhere? Something that emails out an invite link?

We've found [the docs on Permissions and Authorization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) and many SO questions on customizing functionality for types of users, yet we couldn't find any on restricting account creation itself, so perhaps we're missing something.

We could start creating different types of users, but we're wary of getting ahead of ourselves by attempting a more advanced solution before figuring out this basic step. Are we approaching this in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day, there could be many ways to achieve what you're asking. A simple trick could be to use [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/validators/).

As the tutorial you followed does not dive in details, you will have to make extra steps.

I don't know your project structure, therefore I assume you know django's basics.

#### Create a custom validator

In a file called `validators.py` add following (c.f [django EmailValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/validators/#emailvalidator)) :

```py
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

EMAIL_LIST = []

validate_email = EmailValidator(allowlist=EMAIL_PATTERN)
```

Change EMAIL_PATTERN as you wish.

#### Create a custom form

In a file called `forms.py` add something as follow :

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from validators import validate_email


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), validators=[validate_email])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "username",
            "email",
            "password1",
            "password2",
        ]
```

#### Create a custom signup view

In your `views.py`

```py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from forms import CustomUserCreationForm

class SignupView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    template_name = "the-place-of-your/registration-template.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("you-custom-success-url-name")
```

You will have to create a custom template.

#### Edit your urls

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path("signup/", SignupView.as_view(), name="signup"),
    ...
]
```

My modest demonstration is a way to achieve a restriction on email validation using `allowlist` arg. There is many other ways to do so.

Comment: Thank you, looks amazing but I'm struggling to implement this. Could you please clarify in which app validators.py and forms.py should be created? The tutorial made "projectname/accounts" and idk if these belong in them or another app. Also, should `EMAIL_PATTERN` and `EMAIL_LIST` be named as the same variable?

Comment: Also, is `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError` being used? Do we need to raise a validation error if email isn't in the list or is that handled elsewhere?

Comment: Actually, you might create it wherever you want as long it is clear for you and the people with whom you work. For instance, if your app is simple you might create these files where settings.py is found.

Comment: Concerning your second question, you would have to customize EmailValidator to return something that fit you current case.